# Replace a set of characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

How to replace a set of characters where I only know the first and the last one, in between is a variable that is not constant.

All I know is that this string will always start with `&` and it will end with `;`

```
string str = "Hello &145126451; mate!";
```

How to get rid of `&145126451;` ?

So the desired result is:

```
string result = "Hello  mate!"
```

Comment: You want to replace, remove or get this part?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'd like to replace it with an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

The most easiest way is to use `Regex`:

```
    Regex yourRegex = new Regex(@"&.*;");
    string result = yourRegex.Replace("Hello &145126451; mate!", String.Empty);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/waB9tr) with example.

Comment: Probably, you want `@"&.*?;"` pattern (please, notice `?`), otherwise `"Hello &456; mate! &123;"` will be changed into just `"Hello"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko it really depends on OP case...